# Chrome Extension - Running Javascript from Right Click Menu

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am writing a simple Chrome Extension which enables disabled drop-down menus.

If I ran this same script in the Console, it works perfectly. However, through the extension it calls the functions but doesn't do anything.

Thank you in advance for your help.

**manifest.json**

```
{
 "name": "4x6 Mac Menu",
 "manifest_version": 2  
 "version": "0.1.4",
 "description": "Overrides Disabled Drop Down",
 "permissions": ["contextMenus"],
 "background": {
 "scripts": ["sample-click.js"]
 }
}
```

**sample-click.js**

```
function Enable46(info, tab) {
    console.log("Enable 4x6 was clicked.");

    var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('psSelect');
    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        inputs[i].disabled = false;
    }

   console.log("Drop Enabled.");

}

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Enable 4x6",
    contexts: ["page"],
    onclick: Enable46, 
});
```

I also tried another approach to have a listener as background and while I get the console log, the event doesn't actually carry out the function

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "4x6 Enable",
  "description": "Enable 4x6 Print Option on Mac",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": [
    "contextMenus",
    "activeTab"
  ],

  "background": {
     "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["bg.js"]
  }
}
```

**bg.js**

```
/* Create a context-menu */
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: "myContextMenu",   // <-- mandatory with event-pages
    title: "4x6 Label",
    contexts: ["all"]
});

/* Register a listener for the `onClicked` event */
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
    if (tab) {
        /* Create the code to be injected */
        var code = [
        'var input = document.getElementsByClassName("psSelect");',
        'for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) { inputs[i].disabled = false; }'
         ].join("\n");

         console.log("Enable 4x6 was clicked.");

        /* Inject the code into the current tab */
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { code: code });
    }
});
```

Comment: Try adding `"*"` inside permissions array, this should let execute your extension scripts through all the pages

Comment: I suggest you read the [Chrome extension overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) (perhaps along with the pages linked from the overview). The [architecture section](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) has overall architecture information which should help your understanding of how things are generally organized/done. You will also want to read [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Comment: @Frankusky, That's just wrong. See: [Declare Permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions)

Comment: Basically, you're going to need a content script. See the above link to [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) and [`tabs.executeScript()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript)

Comment: @Makyen I also tried that approach and included the code up there. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked. For whatever reason, it had to be split up into 3 files.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Enable Dropdown",
  "description": "Enable Dropdown Menu",
  "version": "0.3",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": [
    "contextMenus",
    "activeTab"
  ],

  "background": {
     "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["bg.js"]
  }
}
```

**bg.js**

```
/* Create a context-menu */
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: "myContextMenu",   // <-- mandatory with event-pages
    title: "Enable Dropdown",
    contexts: ["all"]
});

/* Register a listener for the `onClicked` event */
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
    if (tab) {
        /* Inject the code into the current tab */
        /* chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { code: code }); */
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "content_script.js"}); 
    }
});
```

**content_script.js**

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('psSelect');
    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
   inputs[i].disabled = false;
}

document.getElementById("PrintLabelsPrinter").value = "1-1";
```